# Use firebase cloud function to call remote SOAP service on non google server

Tags: firebase, soap, google-cloud-functions

I have to call a remote server via soap calls. Now using node soap library on a dedicated server (calling a remote soap server) which I want to change for firebase cloud functions.

Is it possible to npm install soap and use this client? Do I need a special plan then?

Comment: Calling to a non-Google service requires that your project is on a paid plan.

Comment: Yes, you can install soap and any other NPM package as long as it's included in your `package.json`. As with what Frank said, you need a paid plan to call non-Google services.